# Error assigning a DataTable Select to a ComboBox

Tags: c#

```
cboUsername.DataSource = oGetUserDetails.Select("USER_LOGIN <>'' AND COMPUTER_NAME<>''");
cboUsername.DisplayMember = "USER_LOGIN";
cboUsername.ValueMember = "COMPUTER_NAME";
```

I am getting the error

> Warning
>   Cannot bind to the new display member.
>   Parameter name: newDisplayMember

`oGetUserDetails` is a `DataTable`

I don't know what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

set the DisplayMember and ValueMember Properties before the DataSource, or set them properly in the designer/aspx file.

Comment: HI IAM USING C# AND WINFORMS AND NOT ASP.NET

Comment: cboUsername.DisplayMember = "USER_LOGIN"; cboUsername.ValueMember = "COMPUTER_NAME"; cboUsername.DataSource = oGetUserDetails.Select("USER_LOGIN<>'' AND COMPUTER_NAME<>''");

Comment: WHEN IAM ASSIGNING IT FIRST IT SHOWING ALL ITEMS IN COMBO AS SYSTEM.DATAROW

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the DataTable does not have Properties for the contained Columns, but is Accessed using the ["columnname"] indexer. In that case, your DisplayMember string should be "Items[\"USER_LOGIN\"]" (and the same applies to the value member.

Comment: AS  oGetUserDetails.Select("USER_LOGIN<>'' AND COMPUTER_NAME<>''") RETURN SYSTEM .DATAROWS

Comment: Can you see the exact columns and any values at debug time ?